# A counter example of the fact that $G^{**}=G$ if and only if G is connected？

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

The dual graph of a plane graph G is a graph that has a vertex for each face of G. The dual graph has an edge for each pair of faces in G that are separated from each other by an edge, and a self-loop when the same face appears on both sides of an edge.

I was going to do exercise 6.1.18 when I was reading West's graph theory textbook.

[image]

I noticed (c), and I think I found a counterexample. I don't know if that's right.

I found a graph $G$ with a cut edge.

[image]

First I figured out his dual graph $G^*$ as shown below in blue.

[image]

When I go further and try to find the dual graph of $G^*$, I find that there is another graph that is not isomorphic with $G$.

[image]

I don't know what's wrong with my thinking.  I hope you can give me some advice. Thanks！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that as you've drawn it, the dual you've constructed would even be a counterexample to part (b). I haven't checked in detail whether part (c) still works out here, but I think you're intended to only cross the bridge *once* with the dual edges -- pardon the MSPaint diagram:

[image]

Comment: You are right ! we may cross the bridge once with the dual edges . Haha, this could be a surprise for (b).

Comment: I should be clear in saying that this construction would only be a "counterexample" to part (b) **if** we considered the original drawing to be a valid construction of the dual, and that I don't believe it was intended to be considered as such. I don't want to appear to be claiming that the *exercise* is incorrect.

Comment: One trick to drawing the dual is to put the edges in first (one edge at right angles to each of the edges in the graph), then add the vertices.